# On the measurability of a special set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is $\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\cup}}[-n,n]$ measurable?

This is a question on Measure Theory of a previous exam period. I can't understand if it's that easy as I find it, or I'm missing something here. I would answer that this is correct because we know that a countable union of measurable sets is measurable.

Comment: That is all there is.

Comment: Also it equals $\mathbb{R}$ and a $\sigma$-algebra always contains the whole space. So not only is it Lebesgue measurable (which I assume is what you mean), but it is measurable for ANY $\sigma$-algebra you put on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, I meant Lebesgue measurable. We haven't yet reached the final chapters which are $L^{p}$ spaces and σ-algebras, so I don't understand that second part. Thank you very much you all!

Comment: How can you study measure without knowing what a $\sigma$-algebra is? That is a very strange book.

Comment: Well, I don't think I can answer your question, since I don't know what a σ-algebra is. Nevertheless, I can provide the link of the book so you can take a quick look. It's distributed freely by the author and my teacher. But I'm afraid it's written in Greek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This union is obviously equal to the whole real line. And the real line is measurable.

Comment: I thought of this too, but isn't there a problem that those are closed sets? I would say that this would be obvious if they where open.

Comment: @Laxuist What point is in this union but not in $\mathbb{R}$, or vice versa?

Comment: No, for take an arbitrary element $r\in\mathbb R$  and observe that there is some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $|r|\le n$.